# dtype argument ignored when index_col is specified in pandas read_excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple excel table that consists of two columns, and i want to read it in a python script using pandas read_excel:

| SKU_ID | Some_Information |
| --- | --- |
| 10001 | example1 |
| 10002 | example2 |

The SKU_ID column should be the index and also its dtype should be *str* (because some SKU_IDs have letters). I was trying to read it with the following code:

`df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', dtype={'SKU_ID': str}, index_col='SKU_ID'}`

But the result of that is a Dataframe in which the index (SKU_ID) is *int64*.

To work around this issue I have done the following:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', dtype={'SKU_ID': str} 
df.set_index('SKU_ID', inplace=True)
```

which basically does the same thing, but keeps the index as type *str*.

Is there a way to set SKU_ID as the index and ALSO as *str* when reading the excel file?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', index_col='SKU_ID', converters={'SKU_ID':str,'Some_Information':str})
```